# responsive separator between divs in flex row container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container, and some divs inside of it. Each div has some content inside of it, that set the width of this div.  between each of the divs, I want to put a responsive separator-div.

I've tried to give the `max-width` property for each of the `responsive` class in the code below, but it not rendering.
I cannot give the `inner-wrapper`'s a fixed width, because it depends on the width of the `inner{#}`.

```
<div class='main'>
  <div class='item-wrapper'>
    <div class='inner1'></div>
    <div class='responsive'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='item-wrapper'>
    <div class='inner2'></div>
    <div class='responsive'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='item-wrapper'>
    <div class='inner3'></div>
    <div class='responsive'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.main{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  height:40px;
  background:yellow;
}
.responsive{
  max-width:200px;
}

.item-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
  background:green;
}
```

to summarize, i expect:

div1 -------------- div2 --------------- div3

such that only the width of the '------' will increase/decrease if i resizing my screen

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this by adding a rule to your flexbox container:

```
myContainer{
    //other properties
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need that much of markup

example

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* new */
}

.responsive {
  flex: 1;
  /* new */
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  /* new */
  border-top: dotted;
  /* new */
}

.main>div:not([class]) {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div>inner 1</div>
  <div class='responsive'></div>
  <div>inner 2</div>
  <div class='responsive'></div>
  <div>inner 3</div>
</div>
```

If you have a **only 3 elements**, then 2 pseudos can become the seperator via order:

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main::before,
.main::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border-top: dotted;
}

.main>div:not([class]) {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.main>div:first-child {
  order: -1
}

.main>div:last-child {
  order: 1
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div>inner 1</div>
  <div>inner 2</div>
  <div>inner 3</div>
</div>
```

more about flex : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/